# Report Portal Does not Attach Logs to Report

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, reportportal

I am working on a way to send report logs to report portal with screenshots attached. I am using XmlHttpRequest module to hit the report portal log endpoint. here is my code.  But this code doesn't work, instead I get a "json_request_part is missing" response message. What am I doing wrong, I followed the docs here [docs](https://github.com/reportportal/documentation/blob/master/src/md/src/DevGuides/reporting.md#batch-save-logs)

```
  try {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    const body = {
    itemUuid: 'gsgasgh-dsjdbbdjsbd',
    launchUuid: 'hshu1qqqqjjhdh-ddjdh',
    time: '1555677888',
    message: 'failed',
    level: 40000,
    file: {
      name: 'screenshot.png',
    },

  };

    request.open('POST', `http://rp.com/my_project/log`, false); // `false` makes the request synchronous
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${config.token}`);
    request.send(JSON.stringify(body));

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status <= 299) {
      const { responseText } = request;
      console.log(responseText);
    } else {
      console.log(`Unexpected Response Returned: ${request.responseText}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending binary data is a bit more complicated, you have to form your multipart request in special format. The format is pretty well [described in this guide](https://github.com/reportportal/documentation/blob/master/src/md/src/DevGuides/reporting.md). Notice that first part of your request should contain JSON with log message and files names from another parts of multipart.
In addition, [there is already implementation for Javascript](https://github.com/reportportal/client-javascript) maintained by ReportPortal's team.
You may also find this snipped helpful:

```
    buildMultiPartStream(jsonPart, filePart, boundary) {
    const eol = "\r\n";
    const bx = `--${boundary}`;
    const buffers = [
        // eslint-disable-next-line function-paren-newline
        Buffer.from(
            // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-template
            bx + eol + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json_request_part\""
            + eol + "Content-Type: application/json" + eol
            + eol + eol + JSON.stringify(jsonPart) + eol,
        ),
        // eslint-disable-next-line function-paren-newline
        Buffer.from(
            // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-template
            bx + eol + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + filePart.name + "\"" + eol
            + "Content-Type: " + filePart.type + eol + eol,
        ),
        Buffer.from(filePart.content, 'base64'),
        Buffer.from(`${eol + bx}--${eol}`),
    ];
    return Buffer.concat(buffers);
}
```

Comment: Hey I ended up using report portal's javascript client https://github.com/reportportal/client-javascript , thanks